# how to Store app data and prevent data to get lost and also make app work at background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a intermediate flutter developer and working on my first commercial app And I have almost created whole  app ui but problem is when i close my app all data get lost . so how can i prevent it + how can i make my app work at background when app is close like in clock app . In clock app even if app is closed then also we get alarm at the timing we set .  It is not possible to provide whole app code thats why i am explaining it in words . Hope you guys will understand the problem and provide best answer  .

Comment: What kind of data lose are you talking about?

Comment: @Diwyansh I mean when app is closed whole app  gets restart and i have to start whole from beginning .

Comment: By data you mean like login details ? right?

Comment: @Diwyansh no , i mean all list(items) added by user and also their favourite items.

Comment: @pro grammer Those kind of items should be stored on a backend, items added by the user and their favourite items should be sent to a backend to be stored in the DB so users can be able to access no matter what device they login with, I'd recommend making use of Firebase if you do not have an API to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use internal data base concept to save user data like JWT key , user id, first name ,last name or app content for offline usage like blog articles ,pos system data for offline usage

- Use [Shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save basic data like user data, JWT but less secure
- but if you need save complex data and need query or filter you can use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) and you can keep data more secure

***And Alarm is totally deferent approach,***

when we schedule alarm,alarm manager schedule task on system alarm services and wakeup app with [`intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) and flutter [`Isolate class`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

We divide your question into two parts.

**Question 01: How to store data locally :**

- You can use key-value storage like [Shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)
- If you are familiar with SQL you can use **[SQLite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)**
- If you are familiar with NoSQL you can use database like [sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast)

These are some of the popular databases that you can use with flutter. And much more available at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages). But you want to use a database with your task. As an example simply store the user name or user id you can use **Shared preferences**

**Question 02: Make Alarm Application :**

For android applications, you can simply use [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager/example)
I suggest you take a deep look at the flutter docs about the subject:

[Background processes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes)

- To run background processes continuously, take a look at this
  package: https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

If you need to show scheduled messages, use [local notifications](http://If%20you%20need%20to%20show%20scheduled%20messages,%20use%20local%20notifications:%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications):

I think by referring to these links you can get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

To store data `locally` you can use `local storage` options like `Database` such as **SQFlite**, **Hive** etc or **SharedPreference** that will save your data locally and to run background process you need to use **MethodChannel** and write platform specific code or you also have the options to use **Isolates**. You may read more using this link

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes